# Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider

Tags: android, firebase

estoy desarrollando una app para Android y ya estoy en la etapa de testing. La app la he estado probando usando un emulador que corre API 29, aunque el proyecto esta configurado para minSdkVersion 23. Sin embargo me arroja el error que lleva de titulo esta pregunta. Investigue acerca de ello y a los que les ha pasado lo resuleven agregando multidex, sin embargo ellos usan minSdkVersion 20 o menor, por lo que multidex si es necesario. Pero como ya mencione mi proyecto es minSdkVersion, y segun el sitio oficial de google de documentacion acerca de multidex, esto esta activado te manera automatica si la minSdkVersion es 21 o mas. Por esta razon, no estoy seguro de que hacer para que funcione; la app corre perfectamente en API 27 o superior, pero desde la 26 hacia abajo no se abre en los dispositivos en los que hago pruebas.

Este es el mensaje Logcat

```
2020-02-17 01:33:43.871 5975-5975/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.Interactive.textmefriends, PID: 5975
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Interactive.textmefriends-e44Txln6Z1Rx80v1hUODRQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Interactive.textmefriends-e44Txln6Z1Rx80v1hUODRQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Interactive.textmefriends-e44Txln6Z1Rx80v1hUODRQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Interactive.textmefriends-e44Txln6Z1Rx80v1hUODRQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6273)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Este es el build.gradle modulo app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Interactive.textmefriends"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206299/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider-error)? No lo referente a multidex, sino a la configuración de _Instant Run_ de Android Studio.

Comment: @SuperG280 si, intente probar con eso pero la opcion de Instant Run ya no existe en el menu desde hace unas versiones de Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Podes probar con lo siguiente en tu proguardrules

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
```

Esto , cuando compiles la app va a mantener la clase `FirebaseInitProvider`

Otra cosa es chequear que las versiones de Firebase esten actualizadas

Podes fijarte en este [LINK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu archivo /app/build.gradle asegura tener definida la dependencia del core de Firebase:

```
dependencies {

    ...
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'

}
```

Ahora crea una clase que extienda de `MultiDexApplication`

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication{

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

y definela para tu aplicación dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
   <application
        ...
        android:name="<paquete de aplicación>.MyApplication"
        ...
        ...>
```

Con esto podrás leer la clase `FirebaseInitProvider` necesaria para que tu proyecto funcione.

Comment: No me funciona, me aparece un nuevo error: Service com.google.android.rcs.service.service.JibeService has leaked